# handle package of product quantity sold

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 `mysql` tables looks like this :

```
 - product(product_id, product_name)
 - order(order_id, order_date)
 - order_detail(order_detail_id, product_id, order_id, quantity)
```

when i want sum of product selled i use this query

```
select order_detail.product_id, sum(order_detail.quantity)
from order_detail 
join order on order_detail.order_id=order.order_id
group by order_detail.product_id
```

This works great for simplified orders where customers choose any number of products and add them to their cart.
However, I'm now faced with the problem of adding `packages`
so i added a new table

```
- Package_Items(package_id,item_id,item_quantity)
```

how can i get `SUM` of all products sold(whether he's in a package or not)

for example i have in table `order_detail`

```
 product_id   | quantity
--------------|-----------------------------
  1           | 2
  2           | 6
  3           | 1
```

and in table `Package_Items`

```
 package_id   | item_id  | item_quantity 
--------------|-----------------------------
  1           | 3        |  7
  1           | 5        |  10
```

the result should be

```
 product_id   | quantity
--------------|-----------------------------
  1           | 2
  2           | 6
  3           | 15
  5           | 20
```

Comment: Where did product_id 5 in the result come from?

Comment: it come from Package_Items because (product_id 5 ) is relied with product_id 1 and the quantity 20=2*10 (2 is quantity of product_id 1 in order_detail and 10 is item_quantity  in table Package_Items

Comment: Consistent column names is a bless...

Comment: I don't understand the logic of '15 quantity' for 'product_id 3' when I count my answer is '8'

Comment: 15= 1 + 2 * 7 (1 is quantity of produt_id 3 in order_detail , 2 is quantity of produt_id 1 in order_detail, 7 is item_quantity in table Package_Items

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word, so this isn't quite your query.

Comment: i know it just for simplification